# Работа приложения в фоновом режиме

Tags: android, java

Здравствуйте, 
Подскажите, пожалуйста , как сделать так, чтобы приложение работало в фоновом режиме. Интересует две ситуации:
1) Выходим из приложения, а оно все равно работает в фоне. 
2) Включаем телефон и приложение сразу начинает работать, т.е. не обязательно открывать его.
 Надо что-то в manifeste прописать ?

Comment: Это Вам надо сервис писать

Comment: [статья раз](http://www.framentos.com/en/android-tutorial/2012/08/01/how-to-start-a-service-at-boot-in-android/) [статья два](http://blog.gregfiumara.com/archives/82) [а тут более подробно](https://www.google.ru/search?q=android+service+run+on+startup&oq=android+servise+run+&aqs=chrome.3.69i57j0l3.15431j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: Для операций в фоновом режиме используют Service. В двух словах не описать так что [service] [service]: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html